# How to create a function in controller and use it in template/view in cakephp 3.xxx

Tags: php, cakephp

I need to use the function in my view/template page.

My code:

```
public function getAppNumber($id = null){

     $aPPLICATIONINFO = $this->AppEstLto->APPLICATIONINFO->find('all', [
     'fields'=>['application_number'],
     'conditions'=>['application_id'=>$id],
     'limit' => 200
     ]);
     foreach($aPPLICATIONINFO as $aPPLICATIONINFO){
        $aPPLICATIONINFOx = $aPPLICATIONINFO;
    } 
     return $aPPLICATIONINFOx;
}
```

Comment: `foreach ($aPPLICATIONINFO as $aPPLICATIONINFO)` is very misleading

Comment: Your loop body overrides the content of `$aPPLICATIONINFOx` on each iteration. Then returns it. It produce the same than just doing `return end($aPPLICATIONINFO)`

Comment: This method seems to be part of the model (it's querying and getting datas). In a MVC pattern, the controller holds the responsibility to build the model, not the view. I would rather get the datas in the controller and pass it to the view

Comment: the code works perfectly, i just need to use it directly to the template/view

Comment: No, code not work perfectly. To use results in template try $this->set('info', $applicationinfo); then in template try debug($info);

Answer (score 1):

You can use set() to use the function variables in your view as given in cookbook:https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/views.html#setting-view-variables

```
public function get_app_number($id = null){

     $applicationInfo = $this->AppEstLto->APPLICATIONINFO->find('all', 
     [
     'fields'=>['application_number'],
     'conditions'=>['application_id'=>$id],
     'limit' => 200
     ]);

     //Create an array
     $applicationArray = new array();

     //Store all results in array
     foreach($applicationInfo as $application){
        $applicationArray = $application;
     }
     // Pass the array to view 
     $this->set(compact('applicationArray'));
}
```

Now, you can use it in your view:

get_app_number.ctp:

```
<?php
 foreach($applicationArray as $application)
 {
   echo $application['application_number'];
 }
?>
```

Comment: Do you need to just call the getAppNumber() from view.ctp file?

Comment: Do you have your function connected to the view ? You should be doing something like this in your ``routes.php`` file inside your Config folder:     ``Router::connect('/get-app-number', array('controller' => 'yourController', 'action' => 'get_app_number'));``

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing something like this in your routes.php file inside your Config folder:

```
 Router::connect('/get-app-number', array('controller' => 'yourController', 'action' => 'get_app_number'));
```

That way you will be able to connect the url that will be used for your view.
Your action corresponds and sends data to your view.
The action is the function that is inside your controller in which you developed for setting the data and variables.
The example of the slug which would be generated:

http://localhost/get-app-number